# I can't understand an error while fitting a weighted ordinal logistic regression

Tags: logistic-regression, survey, ordinal

I'm trying to fit a weighted ordinal logistic regression as my dependent variable, meat consumption, is ordered following three categories (low, medium and high) and my data includes weights.

I'm using the `svyolr()` function from the package `survey` on a survey object I created with the `svydesign()` function.
However, when running the code, I keep getting an error message reading 'response must be a factor', which really puzzles me as I already have converted my outcome dependent variable into a factor...

Here is the code I'm running:

```
DataUBSw$Meat_consum <- factor(DataUBSw$Meat_consum, ordered = TRUE)
modele_ord_w <- svyolr(Meat_consum ~ Geo, design = DataUBSw)
```

with DataUBSw being the survey object created from my original dataframe, with weights included.

I tried running the regression multiple times, to no avail as the same error message keeps popping up:

```
Error in svyolr.survey.design2(Meat_consum ~ Geo, design = DataUBSw) : 
  response must be a factor
```

Would anyone have an idea why I keep getting this error message?

Thanks very much!